# the differences between require and require_once in php

Tags: php

the difference between require and require_once. I just want to know the difference rather than Warning and Fatal Error in php.

Comment: require_once is slower.  Whether or not the difference will be significant depends on your particular code.

Comment: if you search that question at google you would get lots of answer

Answer (score 29):

`require()` includes and evaluates a specific file, while `require_once()` does that only if it has not been included before (on the same page).

So, `require_once()` is recommended to use when you want to include a file where you have a lot of functions for example. This way you make sure you don't include the file more times and you will not get the "function re-declared" error.

[Source](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/22645)

Comment: ++ Good explanations.